# MYSQL - How to match a field with commas in it using like?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a single record from my news feed. I pass it year, month and the news article title. I do the match based where the year = year and month = month and then I use like for the title:

```
LIKE '%title%'
```

this works in every case except when the title contains commas. Why doesn't this:

```
LIKE '%thank you donors volunteers and guests%'
```

match what's in the field: `Thank You Donors, Volunteers and Guests`

But if I put in the commas:

```
LIKE '%thank you donors, volunteers and guests%'
```

it matches it. How can I tell it to match the commas if I don't know the location of them?

Comment: You are looking for [Full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be best served using boolean full text searches, you can customize your query to your parameters, I won't write the query for you but you can figure out how to here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match because it is not the same string. `%` is a placeholder for any string but the rest of the content has to match exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Use INSTR(), for example

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE INSTR(field, "SEARCH STRING") > 0
```

INSTR() returns  the starting index of a the first instance of the string that is to be matched starting with character index 1 so you can use it in a similar manner to LIKE without the function specific special character considerations.